# How does use of "my" keyword distiguish the results in perl?

Tags: perl, scripting, pattern-matching, output, string-matching

I dont understand how the "my" keyword works here. This is my perl script.

```
$line = ' sdfaad(asdvfr)';
```

code1:

```
if ($tmp = $line =~ /(\(\s*[^)]+\))/ ) {
    print $tmp;
}
```

Outputs:

```
1
```

code2:

```
if (my ($tmp) = $line =~ /(\(\s*[^)]+\))/ ) {
    print $tmp;
}
```

Outputs:

```
(asdvfr)
```

Why are the two outputs different?  Does it have to do with the use of `my`?

Comment: See [Mini-Tutorial: Scalar vs List Assignment Operator](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129)

Comment: Note that `printf $tmp;` makes no sense. You want `printf "%s", $tmp;` or `print $tmp;`

Comment: yes! just cheked the difference online. Thanks. But the end results of both are same right? I cant find any difference between printf and print followed by a single argument.

Comment: Certain characters are special in a format string (`printf`'s first arg). You've already seen a difference without realizing it. Try with `my $tmp = '%s';`.

Comment: got the difference. thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not `my` that makes the difference, but scalar/list context. Braces around `$tmp` are imposing list context,

```
if (($tmp) = $line=~ /(\(\s*[^)]+\))/ ) # braces makes difference, not 'my'
```

while `my` only declares variable as lexical scoped one.

Comment: could you please explain a little more

Answer (score 2):

Perl has two different assignment operators; a list assignment operator and a scalar assignment operator.  A list assignment gives its right operand list context, while a scalar assignment gives its right operand scalar context.  A match operation returns differently depending on this context.

Which operator `=` is depends on what is on the left side; if it is an array, a hash, a slice, or a parenthesized expression, it is a list assignment; otherwise it is a scalar assignment.